# Datatemplate binding should work but doesn't. is there an external source for this?

Tags: wpf, binding, datatemplate

I have a content control that doesn't show the binding data only the static texts:

```
<ContentControl Name="Detail" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource detailsAdListingTemplate}" 
            Margin="9,0,0,0"/>

<DataTemplate x:Key="detailsAdListingTemplate" >
            <Grid Margin="5,5,5,10">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="113"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,8,0"
                           Name="title"
                           Style="{StaticResource smallTitleStyle}">Title:</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Name="DescriptionDTKey" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
                    Text="{Binding Path=Title}" 
                    Style="{StaticResource textStyleTextBlock}"/>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,8,0"
                           Name="price"
                           Style="{StaticResource smallTitleStyle}">Price:</TextBlock>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="$" Style="{StaticResource textStyleTextBlock}"/>
                    <TextBlock Name="PriceDTKey" 
                        Text="{Binding Path=Price}" 
                        Style="{StaticResource textStyleTextBlock}"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,8,0"
                         Name="date"
                         Style="{StaticResource smallTitleStyle}">Date:</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Name="DateDTKey" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" 
                  Text="{Binding Path=Date}" 
                  Style="{StaticResource textStyleTextBlock}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,8,0"
                            Name="subCategory"
                            Style="{StaticResource smallTitleStyle}">Subcategory:   </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Name="SubCategoryDTKey" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" 
                    Text="{Binding Path=SubCategory.Name}" 
                    Style="{StaticResource textStyleTextBlock}"/>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,8,0"
                            Name="owner"
                           Style="{StaticResource smallTitleStyle}">Owner:</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Name="OwnerDTKey" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" 
                    Text="{Binding Path=User.Username}" 
                    Style="{StaticResource textStyleTextBlock}"/>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,8,0"
                           Name="location"
                           Style="{StaticResource smallTitleStyle}">Location:  </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Name="locationDTKey" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" 
                    Text="{Binding Path=Location}"
                    Style="{StaticResource textStyleTextBlock}"/>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,8,0"
                           Name="Body"
                           Style="{StaticResource smallTitleStyle}">Body:</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Name="BodyDTKey" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" 
                    Text="{Binding Path=Body}" 
                    Style="{StaticResource textStyleTextBlock}"/>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

I set the Detail.DataContext=ad; (where ad is a proper Ad object that has all the data and all the properties in the {Binding Path=Property}.

IT USED TO WORK FINE. I don't remember editing it. I don't know what I did to the application but now the data template
only shows the static texts - for example Title: but no actual title.So only the bindings don't work.

I'm sure there is nothing wrong with the xaml code above and it should work.

Is there an "external" other source that may be causing this problem?

Comment: I am using Prism regions, Prism with MEF nothing fancy just a few exports and imports. Could the MEF Container mess up things?

Comment: I check at runtime via a button click that the Detail.DataContext is set to an object of type Ad that has all the data. Still it doens't show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ContentTemplate` is the template used to display `ContentControl.Content`, which you are leaving as `null`

Either set `Detail.Content = ad;` (instead of `Detail.DataContext`), or bind your `ContentControl.Content` property to the current DataContext.

```
<ContentControl Name="Detail" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="9,0,0,0"
                Content="{Binding }"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource detailsAdListingTemplate}" />
```